# in-app transparent gateway

Tags: android, proxy

hope you can point me to the right direction.

I am creating an Android library (without using VPNService) which when integrated to an app, will route all of the tcp/udp traffic of that app to my proxy server. The library should also work on non-rooted devices which means the use of iptables is not an option.

Since the use case is for an in-app transparent gateway, the library does not need to re-route traffic of app other than the one it is integrated with.

I've researched and the usual solution I find makes use of VPNService which is not an option as well. Also found [mitmproxy.org](https://mitmproxy.org) but I'm not sure where to start.

In summary, without modifying the app, how can I re-route traffic to my proxy server and still...
1. not use VPN
2. not use iptables and not require root access

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

> In summary, without modifying the app, how can I re-route traffic to my proxy server

That is not possible, sorry. Apps use a wide range of means for accessing networks, including:

- HTTP client APIs (e.g., `HttpUrlConnection`)
- working with `Socket` directly in Java/Kotlin
- working with POSIX sockets directly in C/C++ using the NDK
- `WebView`
- etc.

You have no means of transparently intercepting most of that, let alone re-routing it to go through your proxy.

You *can* offer APIs to allow developers to configure their apps to use a proxy in some situations. NetCipher does this to help developers integrate with the Orbot proxy, for example.

Comment: thanks for the feedback! I was confident of finding a solution because I was able to use such a library in a past project. Unfortunately the library is not open source but using it to re-route traffic was pretty simple. I just had to initialize the library on app start then it took care of routing all traffic to the proxy server.

I tried to decompile the JAR but since it's compiled with proguard, there aren't many clues. I did see that it was using ServerSockets and ServerSocketChannels. I am not sure if it went as low level as NDK

Comment: Where do I start if I just limit what I'd like to intercept to the following?
HTTP/HTTPS calls, Sockets, and Webview

Comment: @schumi: "I was able to use such a library in a past project" -- name it. "Where do I start if I just limit what I'd like to intercept to the following?" -- there is no documented and supported way of transparently intercepting the communications via any of those approaches.

Comment: I cannot disclose publicly since it's proprietary tech. I tweeted you a few hours ago